# joomla module, how to redirect and show some info

Tags: php, joomla

have a joomla module template like this

```
   <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" name="find" method="post">

<p>Places</p>
<select id=pp name=place_info>
    <?php
    foreach ($getPlaces as $place_id => $place_name) {
        echo "<option value=" . $place_id . ">" . $place_name . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

I get the information in helper.php from database.
What i need is, if i click on submit button to redirect me to page and show some information from database. For example if i chose some option from select menu and click submit, i need to get into a page with my content from database.
joomla 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the 'option' hidden form field to choose which component will handle your request, and then any other fields like 'task' that will select a task to handle the request. Some components may also need other parameters, such as 'article_id'.

So, if your form was posting to a custom component called 'mycomponent', and the task was 'showresults', your form would look like this:

```
 <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" name="find" method="post">

<p>Places</p>
<select id=pp name=place_info>
    <?php
    foreach ($getPlaces as $place_id => $place_name) {
        echo "<option value=" . $place_id . ">" . $place_name . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="mycomponent" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="showresults" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps.